# How do I use NavLink in React Static 7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components, react-static

I am updating a React Static website that was created with version 5.9.12 to version 7.2.2.

It seems that `NavLink` was removed from React Static.
With the following code I get an error: `Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined.`

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-static";
import styled from "styled-components";

const NavLinkStyled = styled(NavLink)`
  color: #444;
`;

export default ({ link }) => (
  <NavLinkStyled to={link}>
  </NavLinkStyled>
);
```

I couldn't find in the React Static documentation or on the Internet if it was really removed.

Do I need to replace `NavLink` with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a router, like `@reach/router` and replace the `NavLink` by `Link`, this is the only way I could do it.